# Convert column names to lower case while stacking data objects stored with different case styles

Tags: r

I've several data objects nested in a huge object which I need to stack using `rbind`. However, before stacking these, I need to convert column names to lower case, once the data objects were stored with different case styles. How could I make this happen?

#### Toy data

```
   df <- list(structure(list(a = 1:3, x = c(-1.99, -1.11, -0.34), y = c("C", "B", "A")), .Names = c("a", "x", 
"y"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)), structure(list(a = 1:3, x = c(-0.44, -1.07, 
-0.23)), .Names = c("A", "x"), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L)), structure(list(
    a = 1:3, x = c(-0.62, -0.60, -0.06
    ), y = c(3L, 2L, 1L)), .Names = c("a", "X", "y"), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L)))


lapply(df, names)
```

#### rbind

```
data.table::rbindlist(df, fill=TRUE, idcol = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using `lapply`. However, it creates a duplicate of the original list.

```
df_lower <- lapply(df, function(x) setNames(x, tolower(names(x))))
```

Comment: You can replace `{names(x) <- tolower(names(x)); return(x)}` with `setNames(x, tolower(names(x)))`

Comment: @Imo: Thanks for the hint. I did not know this function.

Answer (score 0):

Design a function and use `lapply` to apply that function to all the data frames. This will change all column names to lower cases.

```
colname_fun <- function(dt){
  dt <- setNames(dt, tolower(names(dt)))
  return(dt)
}

lapply(df, colname_fun)
```